# How create an animation of osculation circle to a parametric curve with circle3D?

Tags: animation

How create an animation of osculation circle to a parametric curve with below circle3D:

```
circle3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 1, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, 
  angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] :=  
  Composition[
    Line,
    Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre], #] &, Map[Append[#, Last[centre]] &, #] &,
    Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most[#]], Last[#]] &,
    Level[#, {-2}] &,
    MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &,
    DiscretizeRegion,
    If
    ][First[Differences[angle]] >= 2 Pi,
   Circle[Most[centre], radius],
   Circle[Most[centre], radius, angle]
   ]
```

Answer (score 6):

For illustrative purposes:

Example parametric curves:

```
p[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0.1 t}
lj[t_] := {Sin[3 t + Pi/2] Cos[t], Sin[3 t + Pi/2] Sin[t], Sin[2 t]}
```

Osculating circles:

```
oc[f_, t_, p_, r_] := Module[{tg, n, b},
  {tg, n, b} = FullSimplify[FrenetSerretSystem[f[t], t]][[2]];
  ParametricPlot3D[(f[t] + r Cos[s] tg + r Sin[s] n + r n) /. 
    t -> p, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

Visualization:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[f /. {"helix" -> p1, "other" -> p2}, 
  oc[f /. {"helix" -> p, "other" -> lj}, t, a, r]], {f, {"helix", 
   "other"}}, {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, {0.1, 0.2}}, 
 Initialization :> (p1 = ParametricPlot3D[p[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]; 
   p2 = ParametricPlot3D[lj[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**An explanation, not an answer.**

An oscultating circle is tangent to the curve and has the same (instantaneous) curvature at the point of tangency as the curve itself.

[image]

Comment: Yes some thing like this but in 3D space.